# Beginner having trouble with checking equality

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I'm trying to use Mathematica to check answers of my calculus problems, and I'm getting behavior that I don't understand.

[image]

Comment: You seem to be trying random functions without reading up on them or understanding them. Don't do this. Read their documentation, look up what they do.  To check mathematical equality, only use `==`, possibly followed by a `Simplify` / `FullSimplify` (perhaps with assumptions).

Comment: Please post actual code rather than an image. It makes it easier to copy & paste. Note that `===` ([`SameQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SameQ.html)) only yields `True` if the expressions are identical. Try `0 === 0.` vs `0 == 0.`.

Answer (score 5):

The return value of `==` is already a Boolean (`True` or `False`) -- provided that Mathematica can decide wether it's true or not; otherwise it returns the input in unevaluated form.

`Equal` is merely the `FullForm` of `==`. Note that if `Equal` gets only one argument (as it was the case in the end of your example), it always returns `True` since every entity is equal to itself. For example, `Equal[1 == 2]` returns `True`. The `FullForm` of this would be `Equal[Equal[1, 2]]`.

`TrueQ` is not meaningful here at all.

The FullForm of `===` is `SameQ`. It really depends on how expressions are written down wether `SameQ` will evaluate to `True` or not. So, as Szabolcs suggested, don't use `===` until you really know what it does. Use `==`.

Comment: I used TrueQ because when I tried using Wolfram|Alpha with "does (expression) equal (expression), which is what I've been using before Mathematica, the code shows that they use TrueQ.

A lot of the time if I just use ==, I get my input back. So this means that Mathematica can't decide? How can it not? Are the expressions too complicated? Why can't it just plug in some number for x and see if they are numerically equal?

Comment: Sometimes expressions are to complicated. Sometimes, it cannot be decided without further knowledge. For example, `x == Conjugate[x]` is not decidable. Plugging in some numbers does not help; equality may or may not hold for other numbers.

Answer (score 1):

As well as `Simplify` and `FullSimplify`, `Apart`, `Expand`, and `Factor` (among  others) may be useful in checking for equality as the OP envisages.

```
Factor[D[Sqrt[(x + 2)/(x - 1)], x]] == OPSoln
```

> True

The functions may need to be applied, either separately or in combination, to both sides of `==`

```
Apart@D[Sqrt[(x + 2)/(x - 1)], x] == Apart@OPSoln
Simplify[D[Sqrt[(x + 2)/(x - 1)], x]] == OPSoln
Apart@Expand@D[Sqrt[(x + 2)/(x - 1)], x] == Apart@Expand@OPSoln
```

> True
>   True
>   True

where

```
OPSoln = 1/2 ((x + 2)/(x - 1))^(-1/2)* -3/(x - 1)^2
```